# vhdl error : near "ladder": (vcom-1576) expecting IS. #

Tags: vhdl

near "ladder": (vcom-1576) expecting IS.
near "ladder": (vcom-1576) expecting IS.
near "ladder": (vcom-1576) expecting IS.
near "ladder": (vcom-1576) expecting IS.
near "ladder": (vcom-1576) expecting IS.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.ALL;



ENTITY tb ladder IS

END tb ladder;
ARCHITECTURE behavior OF tb ladder  IS

COMPONENT ladder

PORT(A : IN std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
     B : IN std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
     CIN : IN std_logic;
     SUM : OUT std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
     COUT : OUT std_logic
     );
END COMPONENT;


signal A : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0100');
signal B : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '1001');
signal CIN : std_logic := '0';
signal SUM : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal COUT : std_logic;


BEGIN


uut: ladder PORT MAP (
A => A,
B => B,
CIN => CIN,
SUM => SUM,
COUT => COUT
);

stim_proc: process begin

wait for 2 ns;
A <= "0100";
wait for 5 ns;
B <= "1001";
wait for 3 ns;
CIN <= "O";

wait for 2 ns;
A <= "1101";
wait for 5 ns;
B <= "0011";
wait for 3 ns;
CIN <= "1";

wait for 2 ns;
A <= "0100";
wait for 5 ns;
B <= "0110";
wait for 3 ns;
CIN <= "0";

wait for 2 ns;
A <= "1101";
wait for 5 ns;
B <= "1100";
wait for 3 ns;
CIN <= "1";

wait for 2 ns;
A <= "0100";
wait for 5 ns;
B <= "1001";
wait for 3 ns;
CIN <= "0";

end process;

END ;
```

so, my error is:

> Error: C:\Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a\examples\tb ladder.vhd(7): near "ladder": (vcom-1576) expecting IS.

And if you know my error, correct my code for me please.

Comment: The name should be one word. You can’t have “tb ladder”, change it to “tb_ladder” for example and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Entity names must be a single word. You have `tb ladder` and the compiler is expecting there to be a single word followed by `IS`. Use a name like `tb_ladder` to fix this.